# Accessing the length of child nodes returns twice the original count

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I've been trying to iterate the child nodes by getting the length of a `item` node. But, it shows double the size of the original length.

This is the XML code i've been using,

```
    <item>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <comments>http://www.example.com/#comments</comments>
        <pubDate>Mon, 19 Jan 2015 04:05:39 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Exampple]]></dc:creator>
        <category><![CDATA[Hot News]]></category>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.example.com/?p=72278</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[<p>Some Description</p>]]></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Some description content.</p>]]></content:encoded>
        <wfw:commentRss>http://www.example.com/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
    </item>
```

Java Code :

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
int length = nl.getLength();
Log.d("check", "Item i count = " + length); //shows 10
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Node currentNode = nl.item(i); // Get the first item
    String nodetestName = currentNode.getNodeName();
    NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes(); // Get the child nodes of first item
    int clength = nchild.getLength(); // Get the length of child nodes of first item (Shows 21 but original length is 10)
```

What should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Dom parser reports wrong number of child nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649396/java-dom-parser-reports-wrong-number-of-child-nodes)

Answer (score 2):

try ignore the whitespace, it works for me.

```
docBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are adding item in NodeList without empting the list.

Comment: how to empty the list?

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten that the whitespace text nodes in between the child elements are also nodes, and are included in the result of getChildNodes(). Can't remember how best to fix this: I avoid using DOM like the plague.

Comment: How should i handle the whitespace text nodes or at least any other best alternative to DOM which is every effective in terms of handling the data and speed? btw thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I forget whether DOM has options to build the tree without whitespace text nodes. If I'm using Java to access tree representations of XML, my preferred models are XOM or JDOM2. But wherever possible, I try to do all XML manipulation in languages designed for the job: XSLT and XQuery. Even in Java, I will do nearly everything by calling out to XPath.